# Adding items to sets in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a list of dictionaries that maps different IDs to a central ID. I have a document with these different IDs associated with terms. I have created a function that now has a key the central ID from the different IDs in the document. The goFile is the document where in the first column there's an ID and in the second one there's a GOterm. The mappingList is a list containing dictionaries in which the ID in the goFile is mapped to a main ID.
My expected output is a dictionary with a main ID as a key and a set with the go terms associated with it as value.

```
def parseGO(mappingList, goFile):

    # open the file
    file = open(goFile)

    # this will be the dictionary that this function returns
    # entries will have as a key an Ensembl ID
    # and the value will be a set of GO terms

    GOdict = {}
    GOset = set()

    for line in file:

        splitline = line.split(' ')

        GO_term = splitline[1]
        value_ID = splitline[0]


        for dict in mappingList:
            if value_ID in dict:
                ENSB_term = dict[value_ID]

        #my best try
        for dict in mappingList:
            for key in GOdict.keys():
                if value_ID in dict and key == dict[value_ID]:
                  GOdict[ENSB_term].add(GO_term)

        GOdict[ENSB_term] = GOset

    return GOdict
```

My problem is that now I have to add to the central ID in my GOdict the terms that are associated in the document to the different IDs. To avoid duplicates i use a set (GOset). How do I do it? All my try end having all the terms mapped to all the main IDs.
Some sample:

```
mappingList = [{'1234': 'mainID1', '456': 'mainID2'}, {'789': 'mainID2'}]
```

goFile:

```
1234    GOTERM1
1234    GOTERM2
456    GOTERM1
456    GOTERM3
789    GOTERM1
```

expected output:

```
GOdict = {'mainID1': set([GOTERM1, GOTERM2]), 'mainID2': set([GOTERM1, GOTERM3])}
```

Comment: You are re-using the same set object over and over again. Create a new set for each key. What is your input and expected output?

Comment: My expected output is a dictionary with a main ID as a key and a set with the go terms associated with it as value.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data ([edit] your question, and give us the expected output for that input).

Comment: How you have your examples and desired output written, both mappingList, and GOdict are lists, however they don't follow legal list syntax (and you define GODict as a dict earlier).  Did you mean to make them dictionaries?  If so, how is "456, 789" stored?

Comment: mappingList is a list of dictionaries and GOdict is a dictionary, I'll try to edit them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't use the variable name 'dict', as it shadows the built-in `dict` class, and *will* cause you problems at some point.

The following should work for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parse_go(mapping_list, go_file):
    go_dict = defaultdict(set)

    with open(go_file) as f:                    # Better garbage handling using 'with'
        for line in f:
            (value_id, go_term) = line.split()  # Feel free to change the split behaviour
                                                # work better for you.
            for map_dict in mapping_list:
                if value_id in map_dict:
                    go_dict[map_dict[value_id]].add(go_term)

    return go_dict
```

The code is fairly straightforward, but here's a breakdown anyway.

We use a default dictionary instead of a normal dictionary so we can eliminate all that `if in` or `setdefault()` boilerplate.

For each line in the file, we check if the first item (`value_id`) is a key in any of the mapping dictionaries, and if so, adds the lines second item (`go_term`) to that `value_id`'s `set` in the dictionary.

EDIT: Request for doing this without `defaultdict()`.  Assume that `go_dict` is just a normal dictionary (`go_dict = {}`), your for loop would look like:

```
        for map_dict in mapping_list:
            if value_id in map_dict:
                esnb_entry = go_dict.setdefault(map_dict[value_id], set())
                esnb_entry.add(go_term)
```

Comment: Many thanks! It worked! Can I ask if there is a way of doing it without using the defaultdict?

Comment: @Suapu Sure, if for any reason you don't want to return a defaultdict, and want a normal dictionary (like raising KeyErrors elsewhere), use `setdefault`, and then add the value to the set (code edited to include this).